# Kohana ORM ordering

Tags: orm, sql-order-by, kohana

I'm using Kohana's ORM library, and I'm wondering if there is any way to select DB records in a particular predetermined sequence.

```
$products_ids = array('5', '6', '1', '33', '2');

$products = ORM::factory('Product')->where('state', '=', 1)
->and_where('id', 'IN', $products_ids)->find_all();
```

This orders result by primary key (id). So result records ordered like (1, 2, 5, 6, 33). How select records by order defined in $products_ids ('5', '6', '1', '33', '2')?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

`$products = ORM::factory('Product')->where('state', '=', 1)
->and_where('id', 'IN', $products_ids)->order_by('product_id', 'desc')->find_all();`

Note the added [order_by()](https://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#order_by) in the string above.

You can order your results now. It has more cool features like [group_by()](https://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/api/ORM#group_by).

Read the documentation and you will find more unexpected magic in ORM.

Comment: Thank's for answer, Ramon! I am using order_by all the time. Adding ->order_by('product_id', 'desc') will order results in sequence ('33', '6', '5', '2', '1'). That's not what I need. The question is how to order result by order defined in $products_ids ('5', '6', '1', '33', '2').

Comment: Hmm. In that case I would add a 'order'  in the database as column, then you can order in that one. Let me know what you would think about that.

Comment: It would be a solution in case order stored before we build database request. In my case (non-standard situation) ordering depends on each user choise and plays key role for statistics collection. I get products ordering from POST-data array, so ordering is unknown value until form submited. But maybe it's a scenarios problem.

Comment: I know this is bad solution but any way:


<pre><code>
 $products_ids = array('5', '6', '1', '33', '2');
 $products_object = ORM::factory('Product');
 $products_ordered = array();
 foreach($products_ids as $products_id)
 {
  $products_ordered[$products_id] = $products_object->where('id', '=', $products_id)->find();
 }
</code></pre>

Comment: I will check this in a moment :)

Comment: "bad solution" because it is a cycle DB-requests. There should be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL you can have conditions in order by clause where if the condition match it gets treated as 1 and 0 on fails.

The code for the example would be:

```
$products_ids = array('5', '6', '1', '33', '2');

$products = ORM::factory('Product')->where('state', '=', 1)->and_where('id', 'IN', $products_ids);
foreach($products_ids as $product_id)
{
    $products->order_by(DB::expr('id='.$product_id), 'desc');
}
$products = $products->find_all();
```

In MySQL it would look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM products WHERE ... ORDER BY id=5 DESC, id=6 DESC, id=1 DESC, id=33 DESC, id=2 DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you wan do so stupid thing, but 2 answers you have. (For stric problem. But probably you don't show full background.

I propose 2 scenarios:

1. Products on page category - add column for order it to table.
2. Display shopping chart - order by order_item_id

BTW: ORM is comfortable, but slow, so if you nedd it only for display (read operation) better is using raw query. Here solution for ORM.

```
public function get_ordered(array $ids){
  if(empty($ids))
    return array();
  $res = DB::select->from($this->_table_name)
           ->where($this->primary_key(),'IN',$ids)
        ->execute($this->_db)->as_array($this->primary_key());
  $out = array();
  foreach($ids AS $one){
    if(isset($res[$one]))
       $out[$one] = $res[$one];
  }
  return $out;
}
```